# Set To: address as the value of the Opportunity owner

Tags: apex

How do I set the value of the To: field to the opportunity owner?

```
global class OpOwnerOldService_Scheduled Implements Schedulable
    {
        global void execute(SchedulableContext sc)
        {
            sendEmailtoOppOwner();
        }

        public void sendEmailtoOppOwner()
        {
            List<Opportunity> listOpportunity = new List<Opportunity>();
            listOpportunity = [SELECT Id, OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id In (SELECT OpportunityId FROM OpportunityLineItem WHERE Product2.Make_unavailable_for_opps_and_proposals__c = TRUE)];

            for(Opportunity opp : listOpportunity)
            {
               Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

                // Strings to hold the email addresses to which you are sending the email.
                String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'someone@example.org'}; 

                // Assign the addresses for the To and CC lists to the mail object.
                mail.setToAddresses();

                // Specify the address used when the recipients reply to the email. 
                mail.setReplyTo('glenn.daly@live.com');

                // Specify the name used as the display name.
                mail.setSenderDisplayName('Salesforce Support');

                // Specify the subject line for your email address.
                mail.setSubject('Historic Service attached to current opportunity : ' + opportunitylineitem.Product2.Name);

                // Specify the text content of the email.
                mail.setPlainTextBody(opportunity.Id +' has been created.');

                // Send the email you have created.
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
            }

            update listOpportunity;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use the [`setTargetObjectId`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm#apex_Messaging_SingleEmailMessage_setTargetObjectId) method.

From the documentation:

> All emails must have a recipient value in at least one of the following fields:
>
> - toAddresses
> - ccAddresses
> - bccAddresses
> - targetObjectId

So instead of:

```
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'someone@example.org'}; 
mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
```

You'd want:

```
mail.setTargetObjectId(opp.OwnerId);
```

Comment: Now that I've made that change, and scheduled the class in the user interface (apex classes then click schedule apex and set days and time), should the code run, or do i need to make any further additions?

Comment: You'll exceed your `sendEmail` limit of 10 if your batch size is above 10 or your batch class provides more than 10 records. See [Apex Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm), and [Batch Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm).

Comment: You'll want to query all records in your `start()` method, and return them to your `execute` method. You'll also want to set your batch size to 10 (See [`System.ScheduleBatch(...)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_scheduleBatch).

Comment: fantastic, thanks very much for your help, it's greatly appreciated! I will give that a try and fingers crossed it runs when I check on Monday :)